# Add new link to sitecore/admin page without changing any existing sitecore files

Tags: sitecore-client, admin-pages

We have created a new .aspx page to download some files from which are created by another service in the root node.
We have placed this page in the **sitecore\admin** folder and is working fine.
the path to the page is sitecore\admin\importFile

Is there a way we can add a new button to sitecore admin page which can then be linked to the new .aspx page without modifying the code?
[image]

Sitecore Version is 9.3

Comment: Which Sitecore version?

Comment: @MarekMusielak: Sitecore version is 9.3

Comment: does this help you? https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/17109/sitecore-9-custom-admin-page

Comment: @GauravAgarwal: I was able to debug this part. It seems like the code behind file  default.aspx.cs has the links which are getting displayed on the sitecore/admin page. But then how is sitecore putting these pages in different sections on the admin page? 
The ask is can we add a new link to the admin page without overriding any init function? I was of the opinion that sitecore is maybe handling the links from core database.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you can't add that as it is a precompiled JS file that creates this and stacks all those links.

But below could be performed to get your link added as a Menu to the Administrator tool page.

1. Go to the `"<wwwroot>\sitecore\admin"`.
2. Then you open a javascript file called "main.bundle.js" **This is not an ideal file to modify but you can try if it doesn't break after testing**.
3. Then you could see something like below. In this, you need to add your code under the section as highlighted.

[image]

4. Then you add the new link you want and this will make sure the link comes and stacks like the menu on the page, make sure you add that under the correct category or you add a new category as well.
5. Sample code for you possibly as below.

```
title: "Custom Pages",
    items: [{
        legacy: !0,
        link: "/sitecore/admin/new.aspx",
        title: "New Page",
        description: "New Custom Page"
    }]
```

Hope this might help.

Comment: Thanks for the infor. Decompiling the code behind didn't give me anything and I was not able to  find the mentioned JS file. Now I understand where the different sections on the admin page are coming from.